# How to override Joomla input.php(JFilterInput class)

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, fatal-error

I want to override `JFilterInput` class on Joomla. The file is on below path:

> [Joomla_Path]/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php

Because this file developed just for non-Unicode characters.So it shows

> Notice: Array to string conversion

on line `233` in many components like `com_finder` that uses this class for Unicode characters. That line is:

```
$result = (string) preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i', '', $source);
```

for this reason I wanted to override this line and same others. firstly I developed a Joomla system plugin to override this file with `onAfterRoute()` method but by following [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9076/joomla-3-plugin-to-override-class-jmenusite) post in stackexchange I changed `onAfterRoute()` method to `onAfterInitialise()` method. But again it shows below fatal error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JFilterInput

Now I'm looking forward to get helps from everybody which solve this problem.
in addition, I use last version of Joomla

Comment: `onAfterInitialise` is the event used once the framework has dispatched the application. Meaning `JFilterInput` already exists, which is why you're getting the error `Cannot redeclare class JFilterInput`. Rather than trying to redefine the class, try extending it

Comment: I understood very helpful tip from your comment. Just could you help a little more; how can I extend this class plz. A link or any sample code with regards

Comment: A demo plugin written by @Don Gilbert can be found here: https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that it return "Notice: Array to string conversion". It usually means that you try to get array variable using string functions. Check what data do you push directly in `$_REQUEST`.

Back to question. You can always use `RAW` type of filter if filtering is to strict.

If you still need to override this class please check this plugin sample:
https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387.