# Change priority of loading Joomla core class and custom core class overrides

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, system-plugin

I would like to know in Joomla framework, there is a way to change priority loading some Joomla core classes after using `JLoader::register()` method in a system plugin developed to override Joomla core classes? or We have to override whole core classes to run this process. of course I saw many suggestions in [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5454/2098) and [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/324/2098) post but they're very messy and confusing.

For this reason, I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387) sample code to override. I just wanted to override JFilterInput class in `filter` folder on Joomla libraries path. But this class imported in other core class, so Joomla doesn't load or register(I don't know) my custom `JFilterInput(input.php)`. I added some track lines and it shows, to load original JFilterInput class not my custom class in below file on line `91` with mentioned code:

> [Joomla_Libraries_PATH]/joomla/input/input.php
>
> Line 91: $this->filter = JFilterInput::getInstance();

Is there a way to change this ordering for registering Joomla Core and Custom classes?

I use last version of Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was bumped to the homepage. In any case, there's a plugin called Joomla Override that allows you to override the core, which is, from our experience, an unstable plugin.

The best solution is to overwrite core files and keep a record of all your overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change it, because it is load during load the cms/application.

During the "PlgSystem**" will be load, you will be able to make the overrides such as dongilbert discribed.

Perhaps you can give an example what do want to do concrete?

Comment: Dear JProof; this post is a question to complete my previous post that I started on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10837/2098   address but I understood which it must be complete with Joomla overriding. Thanks in advanced for every comments and answers. BR